# How do I set up the data for a Friedman Test?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, friedman-test

Below is a small sample of a very large data set (over 10,000 records).  All I'm trying to do is determine if there's a statistically significant difference found in the ordering of supplies among staff from different departments, sub-departments, positions and occupations. There are over 10,000 orders of various stationary supplies. I've already done a Wilcoxon rank sum test on gender and now I need to do it on attributes that have more than two levels.

Could someone please show me how to set up the data?

[image]

Comment: The data for a Friedman test need to be in unreplicated complete block design.  That means that there is one and only one observation for each combination of your blocking variable and your independent variable.  This data does not appear to meet these requirements.

Comment: Sal, I can always transform the categorical variables into dummy variables.  Do I assume from your comment that I would be looking at a vast amount of combinations of variables?

Comment: The point is that Friedman test handles only data in unreplicated complete block design.  If your data can't be arranged like that, it's just not going to work.... One question I have for you though in thinking about an appropriate analysis: If you were considering Position and Trade, for Clerk 0129 for the data you posted, does it make sense to have one observation of 2 total count, or two observations of 1 count apiece?

Comment: They're separate people in different sub-departments.  I assume independence and list it as two observations of 1 count apiece.

Comment: Why not tell us more precisely what you want to know, rather than asking us how to make a 'Friedman test' of it.

Comment: Bruce, all I'm trying to do is determine if there's a statistically significant difference found in the ordering of supplies among staff from different departments, sub-departments, positions and occupations.  There are over 10,000 orders of various stationary supplies.  I've already done a Wilcoxon rank sum test on gender and not I need to do it on attributes that have more than two levels.